# Загрузка массива файлов по одному

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В `html` загрузить несколько файлов сразу можно такой конструкцией:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
```

Но чтобы она загрузила несколько файлов, их надо сразу все выбрать. Как можно сделать загрузку файлов "по одному"? Чтобы каждый новый загружаемый файл добавлялся к этому массиву. Можно конечно вывести 20 кнопок и у тебя будет 20 возможных нажатий, но выглядеть это будет не очень.

Comment: Никак. Прячьте инпуты с уже выбранными файлами и показывайте только один такой инпут в данный момент времени. Или заведите объект `FormData` и добавляйте выбранные файлы в него.

Comment: подходит ли решение с добавление дополнительного инпута при выборе нового  файла?

Comment: @yolosora, думаю, да.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению напрямую через js вносить изменения в файлы инпута нельзя из соображений безопасности, иначе можно было бы поиграться с перебрасыванием ивента на спрятанный инпут с последующим переносом результат в главный ипнут :( Если вы используете в своем софте кастомный браузерный движок, то можете пошаманить с настройками безопасности.

В общем случае можно попробовать вот так добавлять файлы по одному. При каждом новом добавлении добавлять еще один инпут.

```js
$('input').one('change', appendInput);

function appendInput() {
  $(this).parent().append(`<br><label>Файл ${$('input').length+1}</label><input type='file'/>`);
  $(this).nextAll('input:first').one('change', appendInput);
}
```

```css
label {
  padding-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=container>
  <label>Файл 1</label><input type='file' />
</div>
```